# How to store XML files in HBase?

Tags: xml, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to work on following scenarios:

1. I have simple XML data:

   ```
   <main_tag>
       <x>
          <a>name value</a>
          <b>age value</b>
       </x>
       <y>
           <c>country value</c>
       <y>
   </main_tag>
   ```

   I want the above XML file to be stored in HBase. How can we do it?
2. If I have large number of XML files, how can I do bulk loading of files into HBase?

In both the scenarios, I don't want to use HDFS initially.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173983/best-way-to-store-hierarchical-data-in-hbase

Answer (score 0):

Your first question answered by @ravindra. For second question, You have the option of bulk loading where you can use map reduce to read large data, and convert it into HFile format, and then use bulk loading command to load output of map reduce to Hbase. For this, since map reduce reads data from HDFS, you should have large data in HDFS.

It depends on your data too. Look [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/) for more information.

Comment: so, we must use HDFS for bulk loading of xml data? can you please provide an example code which has bulk loading of xml data into hbase